# Firefox Flash Plugin not working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, flash, firefox

My Flash plugin just won't work for Firefox on Linux Mint.

I am running Linux Mint 14 Nadia 64bit.

- Downloaded firefox-27.0.1.tar.bz2
- Extracted it
- Ran ./firefox it works fine
- Downloaded install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
- Extracted it
- Copied the plugin: **cp libflashplayer.so
  /home/gary/.mozilla/plugins/**
- Copied the Flash Player Local Settings configurations: **sudo cp -r
  usr/* /usr**
- Generated dependency lists for Flash Player: **ldd
  /home/gary/.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so**

Plugin still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

start with a command in terminal

`sudo apt-get alien` - it is a converter worth using .

For rpm to deb use code `sudo alien <file-name>.rpm`

for tar.gz use code `sudo alien -k <file-name>.tar.gz`

for tar.bz2 use code `sudo alien -d <file-name>.tar.bz2`

for tgz use code `sudo alien --to-deb ~/<file-name>.tgz`

good luck .

```
~ $sudo alien -d firefox-27.0.1.tar.bz2
```

wait

double click new deb file

[Silverlight](https://app.box.com/s/1n3yobdl8mlsu21yj5o6)

And download chrome this plugin rocks it will enable flash 15 ...

[Pepperflash](https://app.box.com/s/4amzre5wavpk1db5yma8)

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install mint-flashplugin
```

This works from terminal.